# Is it valid YAML to place two anchors in the same name

Tags: yaml

This is my YAML

```
a: &SS Moyshale
b:  *SS
c: &SS Moyshale2
d:  *SS
```

Is this a valid YAML? (I want `d` to be equal to `Moyshale2`)

Comment: Any specific reason to have an extra space before the values of your mapping that have aliases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is valid YAML, according to the [YAML 1.2 specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878):

> When composing a representation graph from serialized events, an alias node refers to the most recent node in the serialization having the specified anchor. Therefore, anchors need not be unique within a serialization.

And therefore `d` should equal the most recent "definition" of `SS`.

Some parsers will throw a warning, which you would have to filter out:

```
import sys
import warnings
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: &SS Moyshale
b:  *SS
c: &SS Moyshale2
d:  *SS
"""

with warnings.catch_warnings():             # ignore the re
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
    data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

You would get the following output and:

```
a: Moyshale
b: Moyshale
c: Moyshale2
d: Moyshale2
```

Without the filter you would also get:

```
..../lib/python3.5/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/composer.py:98: ReusedAnchorWarning: 
found duplicate anchor 'SS'
first occurence   in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 4:
    a: &SS Moyshale
       ^
second occurence   in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 4:
    c: &SS Moyshale2
       ^
  warnings.warn(ws, ReusedAnchorWarning)
```

Please note that aliases on string scalars are (currently) not preserved in `ruamel.yaml`¹ and since the anchors have no associated aliases, they are not included in the output. If you change  `Moyshale` and `Moyshale2` to `[Moyshale]` and `[Moyshale2]` the output would include the anchor `SS` twice:

```
a: &SS [Moyshale]
b: *SS
c: &SS [Moyshale2]
d: *SS
```

---

¹ <sub>This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) a YAML 1.2 parser, of which I am the author.</sub>

Comment: With `ruamel.yaml-0.16.10` the above python script as is does not produce the same output. `b: *SS` and `d: *SS` instead of `b: Moyshale` and `d: Moyshale2`.

Comment: Yes that was 4 years ago, before ruamel.yaml could preserve tags on roundtrip on more primitive nodes like these strings.